# Ideas for a simple angle adjustment/lock for a steel plate arm

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to come up with a better way to adjust the angle between the two steel pieces in the picture, and lock it in place. At the moment I just have a nut and bolt that I loosen and then tighten, but it is very cumbersome.

[image]

What would be perfect is some sort of geared dial that I could turn which maintains the force between the plates so I just turn it to whatever angle I need without loosening and tightening again. I'm just not sure what exactly I would search for.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend closing as "too broad."  You can't overcome the frictional force without loosening *something* -- you might as well just use a long lever arm to force it!  Commercial options include a spring-loaded teflon washer, a planetary gear, or cutting radial ridges into both pieces so they lock into a discrete set of angles.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If u want to answer then answer it below and not as a comment

Comment: @Fennekin Thanks but I don't consider what I wrote worthy of answer-quality

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest extending the fixed bar enough so that a hole could be tapped, then get a [wing head bolt](http://www.mcmaster.com/#91404A505)
and thread it through, holding the bar in place. You are going to have to tighten something if you want to restrict movement.

Comment: Well, no you don't.   I have a desk lamp at home with tensioned joints  similar to the OP's setup.  You overcome the stiction to adjust the lamp angle, then it stays put in that configuration.